How to have default slicer selection based on another slicer
I have two slicers, Month and Week. The Week slicer filters the Month slicer, so whenever I choose a week, it filters to that corresponding month.
There's my question, is there a way when I choose a week, the Month slicer automatically selects the correct month instead of choosing the preselected month?
I want it to automatically select April when I choose a week in April like this.

But right now it requires me to manually select the Appropriate month.



What is your source/model ?

you'd better use a calendar table and create relationships with these slicers... and you can set  your own custom slicer
